# Why can't Firefox 1.5 parse the DOM children of the SELECT drop down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, dom

I'm required to use [Firefox 1.5](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/releases/1.5.html) (yes I know...) for an in house tool, only used on a closed system.

I have a basic html [select](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) drop down menu:

```
<select name="selectName" ID="Select">
   <option value="A" selected>Tom</option>
   <option value="B">Jim</option>
   <option value="C">Nancy</option>
</select>
```

In JavaScript, I would like to extract the name (inner text) of the selected option.

In [Firefox 3.6](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/3.6/releasenotes/) I can do the following:

```
var x = document.getElementById("Select");
var name = x.children[x.selectedIndex].text;
```

and name will contain the string of the selected drop down. (`Tom` by default)

However, when I run this code in Firefox 1.5, I get the following error:

> **x.children has no properties**

Unfortunately, I can't install Firebug on 1.5, as it is not compatible, to get any more information.

I have a JavaScript Error console on 1.5 and that is all.

How else can I get the text of the selected option, that would work with FF1.5.

Is there a JQuery method that would work in this situation?

Also, I'm interested why this does not work in FF1.5

(Is there a compatible JS debugger for FF 1.5?)

Thank You.

Comment: Children isn't a valid DOM attribute in firefox.  I believe that's IE only. see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431861/jquery-each-tr-children-is-undefined-in-firefox-3-0/431898#431898

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<select>` element has an "options" attribute whose value is the array of `<option>` elements. You should be able to use that exactly as you're using "children".  (In fact I think that's a better habit to be in, because the children of the `<select>` aren't necessarily just `<option>` elements.)

Comment: I believe it's an Array-like object called `HTMLOptionsCollection` rather than an Array, but otherwise this is spot on.

Comment: @Tim yes sorry - I meant "array" in the colloquial sense and not the strict Javascript sense I suppose :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
x.options[x.selectedIndex].innerHTML
```

And go here to get an old version of Firebug that is compatible with Firefox 1.5 (looks liek Firebug 1.05 is the latest version that was compatible):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/versions/

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be using "childNodes" not "children"? (yes you can use "options", but might as well know a general solution)  Another option (heh) is select.getElementsByTagName("OPTION").